# How to fix 'No module named Mpi4py' when I installed mpi4py

Tags: openmpi

so I installed `openmpi` and the `mpi4py` library (I made sure to install the python3 version as that gave me an error earlier) and the `mpi4py` library still cannot be found by my python programs.

I tried installing it again using `pip3` and that didn't work, also none of the other questions seem to have helped.

```
import mpi4py
```

And this is the error:

```
Input xml: /home/robotics/spinningup/half_cheetah_variable.xml
Output xml: /home/robotics/gym/gym/envs/mujoco/assets/half_cheetah.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/home/robotics/spinningup/spinup/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from spinup.algos.ddpg.ddpg import ddpg
  File "/home/robotics/spinningup/spinup/algos/ddpg/ddpg.py", line 7, in <module>
    from spinup.utils.logx import EpochLogger
  File "/home/robotics/spinningup/spinup/utils/logx.py", line 14, in <module>
    from spinup.utils.mpi_tools import proc_id, mpi_statistics_scalar
  File "/home/robotics/spinningup/spinup/utils/mpi_tools.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mpi4py import MPI
```